# How does number of items in a hashset effect performance?

Tags: java, hashset

I was looking at the solution to find the longest continuous sequence of integers in an unsorted array. The solution is a 2 pass method, where in the first method all the elements are added to a hashset and in the second pass, we check how many elements are in the hashset to the right of it and to the left of it. It looks like this:

```
temp = n;
while(map.get(temp+1) != null) {
    count++;
    map.remove(temp++);
}
```

where `n` is the current element in the array. In this, why are we removing the element from the hashset after we checked for it? The solution said if we don't remove it, the time complexity becomes `O(mn)` instead of `O(n)`. I thought hashset lookups are independent of contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the HashSet, it has to do with the algorithm. If you don't remove the adjacent numbers from the set, you will reprocess them as first elements of the next sequence.